# Spring boot 1.5.9 will support which version of spring boot admin?

Tags: spring-boot-admin

Currently, we are using spring boot 1.5.9 with eureka .Can anyone tell me know which version of spring boot admin I should use?

Comment: 2x can be used as per document https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#monitoring-spring-boot-1.5.x.
Do not forget to mention spring.boot.admin.api-path=/admin in property file name can be anything and @EnableAdminServer at Application class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the latest from Spring Boot Admin 1.5.x branch, which is currently 1.5.7